# Complex Analysis: Proofs on Re(z) & Im(z)

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-explanation

How do you prove that

$-|z| \leq \Re(z) \leq |z|$ and $-|z| \leq \Im(z) \leq |z|$ ?

With $z=x+iy$ and $z \in \mathbb{C}$.

$\Re(z)= x$ and $\Im(z)=y$

I know that $|z| = \sqrt{x^2 +y^2}$
Similarly  $- |z| = - \sqrt{x^2 +y^2}$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Note that $|z|^2=x^2+y^2$

Comment: Here's a [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference )

Comment: Hint: $x^2\le x^2+y^2$.

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing much. It's an (almost) immediate observation which follows from the fact that a sum of two squares (of real numbers) is always bigger than (or just the same as) each one of the component squares; that is, $$x^2+y^2\ge x^2.$$ Interchanging the roles of $x$ and $y$ gives you  a similar inequality. If you now take square roots of both sides, you get that $$\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\ge |x|,$$ which is equivalent to $$-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\le x\le \sqrt{x^2+y^2},$$ as wanted.

The one for the imaginary part also follows, by performing $x\mapsto y.$